# C#: Interface with Either Number or DateTime

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

My problem can be simplified to a List<> with X and Y coordinates that I'd like to group into an interface or abstract class.  I then have a bunch of other functions that take this abstract class as an argument.  The caveat to this is that the X element is either of a numerical or is a DateTime.  Here's some sample code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
//C# 4.0
abstract class Element : Group<DateTime, double>
{
      public DateTime X {get; set;}
      public double Y {get; set;}
}

public interface Group<T, U>
{
      public T X {get; set;}
      public U Y {get; set;}
}

void OtherObject.Do(List<Group<DateTime, double>> elm)
{
     double[] X = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < elm.Count; i++)
     {
        if (elm[i].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        {
           X[i] = ((DateTime)elm[i].X).TOADate();
        {
        else
        {
           X[i] = elm.X;
        }
     }

     //Other stuff
}

static Main()
{
     List<Element> list = FactoryCreate();
     OtherObject obj = new OtherObject();     

     obj.Do(list);
}
```

I'd like to be able to specify the `List<Group<DateTime, double>>` argument to `Do()` without specifying that the generic types.  I'd just like to be able to do `Do(List<Group> lst)`.

I *could* just eliminate the generic type parameters and use the dynamic data type in Group but I don't feel like thats the best way.

Is there an established pattern to deal with this issue?  I'm 100% open to suggestions as to the correct way to model this data structure/class.

Comment: You have to specify types in Do(), because you call X.TOADate(). Compiler needs to know where to find TOADate() method, so it needs to know what type is X.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. Why exactly do you want to get rid of explicit type arguments in `D()` if that method is actively using the knowledge about them anyway?

Comment: It took me a while to get into this. I think there should be no generic parameters at all. See my "answer" below.

Comment: The Do() method is coded to not care about what time the X property is.  It converts it to a double if it is not a double.  The work in the Do() Method does not care if the X property is a DateTime or a double.  I could essentially convert any Element with a X of type DateTime to double before calling Do(), but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you overcomplicated it. Your DateTime and double both do the same = they store date and time, so go and use one of them and convert values from the other type when needed. Or create your own class DateTimeOrDouble and put it in place of generic parameter. You cannot use generic parameters when you need date or double and need to call ToOADate(). In short: Don't use generic parameters at all, because you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a non-Generic `IGroup` interface with `object` properties and implement it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One more point: You are mixing here public interface and internal implementation. This is a wrong software design. Your interface should just define operations to access your data, and those operations should be independent of internal data representation. Then you should define some classes implemening this interface, i.e. one with DateTime and other one with double as the real data store. None of this needs to use generics.